# Prove that if $4k+1$ is a prime number than for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2k}{j^{4n+2}}$ is a multiple of $4k+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

Prove that if $4k+1$ is a prime number than for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2k}{j^{4n+2}}$ is a multiple of $4k+1$

First I tried proving for n=1

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2k}{j^{6}}=(4k+1)a$ ... (1)

So I realized that

$7\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j^{6}}=(k+1)^7-21\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j^{5}}-35\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j^{4}}-35\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j^{3}}-21\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j^{2}}-7\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j}$

After some calculations I arrived to the conclusion that

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}{j^{6}}= \frac{k(2k+1)(4k+1)(48k^4+48k^3-6k+1)}{21}$

Now we can prove for n=1

On LHS of (1) we have

$\frac{k(2k+1)(4k+1)(48k^4+48k^3-6k+1)}{21}+\frac{k(2k+1)(4k+1)(48k^4+48k^3-6k+1)}{21}$

we can just factor out $4k+1$ In this sum so therefore the statement for n=1 is true

now we must assume that the statement is true for n=a $a\in \mathbb{N}$

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2k}{j^{4a+2}}=(4k+1)b$$

now we must prove the statement is true for $n=a+1$

I've tried some things but ultimately I can't get anywhere after this point. Any help is appreciated

Comment: There might be a short cut where the sum over those values from $2k+1$ to $4k$ are also considered...

Comment: @VincenteMartinez As abiessu suggested, you could also add the sum from $2k+1$ to $4k$, as their sum would be congruent, modulo $4k + 1$, to the sum you're working with. Also, at the bottom of the [Faulhaber polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials) section of Wikipedia's "Faulhaber's formula" article, it indicates there's a factor of what it says is $n + 1/2$ which, with your notation, is $\frac{4k + 1}{2}$. However, you need to show there's either no factors of $4k + 1$ in the denominator, or there's at least one more factor in the numerator.

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{j=1}^{4k}j^{4n+2}$ is twice the given sum, and $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}j^k\equiv 0\pmod p$ if $p$ is prime and $k\not\equiv 0\pmod{p-1}$ (here is [my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3602405) of this well-known fact, but I think it's available somewhere else too).